# Workflow to provide summary of completions in a week

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am looking for a solution to send a weekly summary using SharePoint workflow. The mail body should contain the summary of learning's completed in a week. Is there a way to include these details from the list based on the status?

Comment: What have you implemented so far ? Check [ask]

Answer (score -1):

Yes, This is the basic functionailty of any SharePoint Designer workflow.
Use SharePoint Designer Workflow and you will be able to send regular emails along with the details stored in any particular List. Follow the msdn site on SharePoint Designer workflows and you will get from where to start.